# Direction of induced current and region of higher potential?

Tags: electric-current, potential, electromagnetic-induction

To my original understanding, in a DC/AC circuit the current always flows in the direction of higher potential to a lower potential. But apparently induced current flows from a lower potential to a higher potential? Is this really the case and why is this so? I'm really confused :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A part of Faraday's Law, called Lenz's Law indicates the direction of the induced current, it has to do with the way the magnetic flux is changing, therefore it is all about the effect of the changing magnetic field onto the circuit, not the initial potential on the circuit, if that is the case you're working on! Maybe elaborate on your question a bit more? :)

Comment: Oops, I'm sorry if my question wasnt clear. Yup, I'm kind of (a very big kind of) acquainted with Lenz's law and know that the induced current would be produced in the direction that opposes the change producing it. But some questions (of a straight line wire in a magnetic field) would ask which end of the wire would have a higher potential, then it would always be of opposite direction to the current (e.g direction of current is A to B while B has a region of higher potential). So I'm really confused by that :< Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Hmm, but how is the straight wire said to actually interact with the magnetic field in such a question? There's not really any flux to create an induced current?

Comment: A moving straight wire** so sorry. I have found a question to illustrate what I was saying. The answer is B

Comment: https://ibb.co/6y9xBLw - the question.

Comment: Ah, there's no inducued current here though, the magnetic field is uniform, therefore no magnetic flux change. What's happening here is, the rod is moving towards the right with velocity V and so do the charges inside it. Due to the Lorentz force, the positive charges inside the rod are moving towards point P, and the negative charges move towards Q, you can check that with the right hand rule!

Comment: So after this happens, if you were to suddenly turn the magnetic field off, the charges would evenly spread back out through the rod, by flowing from high to low potential, the Lorentz force is 'forcing' them to the points P and Q, therefore there is no current! :)

Comment: ohhhh icic. But doesnt the right hand rule indicate that a current is being generated from Q to P? With thumb pointing right, index pointing down, then the middle finger would be pointing up (Q to P)

Comment: The three finger version always confuses me, but if you first reach the 4 fingers towards velocity V, then wrap them into the page, in direction of B, you get the direction of the Lorentz force with your thumb, which will be up, towards P, and that is for a positive charge. For a negative charge it is the opposite direction, so positives go to P, negatives go to Q.

Comment: Ohhhh alright I get it now. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Glad to help :), just to clarify, you need a surface through which you can define a magnetic flux in order to create an induced current, in a rod the effects kinda cancel out. The closest example to that would be antennas, which actually interact with the electric field parts of electromagnetic waves.

Answer (score 0):

In a conductor moving perpendicular to a magnetic field, the electrons would experience a Lorentz force which would lead to migration of electrons to one end giving rise to the potential. Unlike under the influence of only electric force, here the potential is caused due to the movement of electrons and not vice versa.
Hence, assuming there's a magnetic field in direction out of the plane, and the conductor is moving down in the plane, by Flemings left hand rule, (index - out, middle- direction of positive charge ie up, thumb- force /motion) the electrons would experience a force towards right. As a result electrons would accumulate on right side making it more negative or at lower potential than other side. Since electrons are moving to right direction of current would be to left (ie the side of high potential) This will continue up till the magnetic and electric forces (now present due to charge separation) are equal.